# After onchange event occur in textinput field , it loses the focus and didn't take any other input

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, flowbite

As I input anything in the textinput field it immediately loses the focus and I have to click again in the textinput to type into it. Modal used is From flowbite-react.

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        name: " ",
        email: " ",
        password: " "
    })

    const { name, email, password } = formData;
    const handleChangeInput = (e) => {


        const { name, value } = e.target;

        setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });

    };


return (

<div>

            <Modal
                show={showModal}
                size="md"
                popup={true}
                onClose={toggleModal}
            >
                <Modal.Header />
                <Modal.Body>
                    <form className="space-y-6" action="#">
                        <div className="space-y-6 px-6 pb-4 sm:pb-6 lg:px-8 xl:pb-8">
                            <h3 className="text-xl font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                                {issignIn ? 'Sign in' : 'Sign up'}  to our platform
                            </h3>
                            {!issignIn && (


                                <div>
                                    <div className="mb-2 block">
                                        <Label
                                            htmlFor="name"
                                            value="Your Name"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <TextInput

                                        name="name"
                                        placeholder="John Cena"
                                        id="name" key="name"
                                        value={name}
                                        onChange={handleChangeInput}
                                        required={true}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            )}
                            <div>
                                <div className="mb-2 block">
                                    <Label
                                        htmlFor="email"
                                        value="Your email"
                                    />
                                </div>
                                
                                <TextInput

                                    name="email"
                                    id="email" placeholder="name@company.com"
                                    key="email"
                                    value={email}
                                    onChange={handleChangeInput}
                                    required={true}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div className="mb-2 block">
                                    <Label
                                        htmlFor="password"
                                        value="Your password"
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <TextInput
                                    name="password" id="password" placeholder="••••••••"
                                    value={password}
                                    onChange={handleChangeInput}
                                    required={true} key="password"
                                />
                                
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex justify-between">
                                <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
                                    <Checkbox id="remember" />
                                    <Label htmlFor="remember">
                                        Remember me
                                    </Label>
                                </div>
                                <a
                                    href="/modal"
                                    className="text-sm text-blue-700 hover:underline dark:text-blue-500"
                                >
                                    Lost Password?
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div className="w-full">
                                <Button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                                    {issignIn ? isFormSubmitted ? 'Logged In ' : loading ? 'Logging...' : 'Login to your account' : isFormSubmitted ? 'Signed Up ' : loading ? 'Creating Account...' : 'Create Account'}
                                </Button>
                            </div>
                            <div className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-300">
                                {issignIn ? (<p>Not registered? <a onClick={signUp} className="text-blue-700 hover:underline dark:text-blue-500">Create account</a></p>) : (<p>Already have a account? <a onClick={login} className="text-blue-700 hover:underline dark:text-blue-500">Login</a></p>)}
                                {/* <a
                                href="/modal"
                                className="text-blue-700 hover:underline dark:text-blue-500"
                            >
                                Create account
                            </a> */}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>

</div>

)
```

As I remove the value and onchange attribute from the textinput the field starts working but then I'm not able to get the values inside the fields.

How can I get the values inside the textfield after typing without losing the focus?

Answer (score 0):

**I've had a similar issue before and found a solution that worked for me.**

I created a separate file for my search function, let's call it **`search.tsx`**, and I placed all the relevant code in there. Then, I imported the function into my main file.

This approach worked well for me, and I would recommend giving it a try.

Let me know if you have any questions or if this solution works for you!